# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure en Java

Tags: java, xampp

Necesito que me ayuden en un error, estoy empezando a trabajar con una base de datos en java, o sea `MySQL` con `XAMPP`, estoy en el sistema operativo **MAC** y estoy usando **Netbeans**.

Este es el código que use en uno de los botones donde insertaba información en la base de datos:

```
try {

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/David_Productions", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("insert into alumnos values(?,?,?)");

        pst.setString(1, "0");
        pst.setString(2, txt_nombre.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(3, txt_grupo.getText().trim());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        txt_nombre.setText("");
        txt_grupo.setText("");

        label_status.setText("Registro exitoso");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Error " + e);

    }
```

Estoy usando en este programa el `.jar`: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar`
y este es el error que me salta(usando un try-catch):

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the
> server.

Acá les dejo el link para descargar el proyecto:

http://www.mediafire.com/folder/twvv4wivfcwnr/Java_28%5BTrabajando%20con%20Bases%20de%20Datos%20con%20MySQL%5D

Por favor ayúdenme

Comment: La bbdd te esta rechazando o no estas apuntando bien a ella.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: pero estoy usando xampp

Comment: La gran mayoria de comentarios en ese link son para mamp

Comment: sobre eso del bbdd no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Qué tiene que ver XAMP o MAMP con Java?

Comment: Este error regularmente sucede al definir incorrectamente algún valor en la conexión, por ejemplo veo que no estas definiendo un password, estas definiendo : "" , estas seguro que no necesita password ?

Comment: si no tengo contraseña por que nunca me la pidio el programa o algo asi, ademas revise en los archivos de xampp y en la password no hay nada

Comment: eso de Xamp y Mamp, no se pero me parece que son diferentes(perdon si soy ignorante en este tema, estoy empezando en bases de datos)

Comment: Observer que la linea Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() esta comentada? La estas ejecutando en alguna otra parte del codigo? importante para cargar el driver.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente en los String de conexiones se debe especificar el **puerto** en el que se encuentra la base de datos de esta forma:

```
jdbc:mysql://ip_bd:PUERTO/nombre_bd
```

Comment: yo estoy usando el puerto 8080

Comment: en mi xampp activo el localhost:8080 -> 80(over SSH)

Comment: Esto no es necesariamente

Comment: Normalmente el puerto 8080 es el puerto de apache, intenta probar con el puerto 3306 (que es el puerto por defecto de MySql)

Comment: no puedo entrar a phpmyadmin con el 3306, ademas es buscado y en MAC creo que esto es diferente.

Comment: El phpmyadmin te ayuda a gestionar visualmente la base de datos, pero no significa que la base de datos esté en ese puerto. Si estás usando XAMPP debes iniciar tanto Apache como MySql, revisa el puerto de MySql y me cuentas

Comment: pero como puedo ver el puerte no se donde puede encontrarlo, estoy usando xampp-mv

Comment: 8080 es el puerto del servidor no de la BBDD

Comment: para verificar el puerto ingresa lo siguiente en una consola donde ya estes logueado en mysql, o desde el phpadmin donde ejecutas tu sql. show global variables like 'PORT'; sin embargo creo que te desplegara el 3306 si le diste solo siguiente y siguiente, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de resolverlo, en MAC Mojave(u otras versiones) es necesario descargar la version de XAMPP normal, verifica que no sea la MV por que esa no permite que el puerto se ejecute bien en el JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

parece que el error esta en la carga de clase y el parametro de acceso a la base de datos. En mi uso personal   Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); solo lo llamo una vez cuando la app inicia o cuando sea requerido y no todas las veces que solicitas una conexion a la base de datos. Mediante el uso de static{} y dentro de la funcion que verifica si es necesario.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class MiConexion {

    private static boolean DRIVERLOADED = false;
    private static String LASTERROR = "";
   

    static {
        //CARGA DEL DRIVER AL INICIAR LA APP.
        LOADDRIVERS();
    }

    private static synchronized void LOADDRIVERS() {
        try {
            DRIVERLOADED = true;
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; //"org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            DRIVERLOADED = false;
            LASTERROR = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    
    public static synchronized Connection ObtenerConexion(){
        Connection conn;
       try {
            if (!DRIVERLOADED) {
                LOADDRIVERS();
            }
            String dbName = "mysql"; //:"mariadb";
            //Aqui modifica tus datos de acceso a la base
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 3306;
            String database = "David_Productions";
            String userName = "usuario";
            String password = "contrasenia";
            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + dbName + "://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password);
            LASTERROR = "";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            conn = null;
            LASTERROR = ex.getMessage();
        }
       
       return conn;
    }

    public static String ObtenerUltimoError() {
        return LASTERROR;
    }

}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
Connection conn = MiConexion.ObtenerConexion();
        if (conn == null) {
            System.out.println(MiConexion.ObtenerUltimoError());
            return;
        }
     //Aqui continuas con tu codigo.
```